# Display Dialog when loading internet

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog, httprequest

I am trying to create a dialog when loading Httprequest. But it load during the i click to intent from last Activity, but not the start of this Activity.

And the dialog just shown in 0.00001sec then dismiss.

Am i implement it wrongly?

Here is my codes

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    HttpPostHandler2 handler = new HttpPostHandler2();
    String URL ="http://xxxxxx";        
    handler.execute(URL);
}

public class HttpPostHandler2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String resultJSONString = null;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public String getResultJSONString() {
        return resultJSONString;
    }

    public void setResultJSONString(String resultJSONString) {
        this.resultJSONString = resultJSONString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,
                AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("core",
                "core1234"));
        String responseContent = "";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        setResultJSONString(responseContent);
        // return new JSONObject(responseContent);
        return responseContent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();  
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        resultJSONString = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: no.you doing it right. then it must be because of your fast internet

Comment: Not so right! Please see my answer!

Comment: I mean , it load about 2s after i click to open this activity from last activity. But when i try to remove the handler.execute(URL), this activity open instantly. So i dont think my internet fast enough for that 0.00001 loading.

Comment: Yeah! You need to move it to `onStart`. Otherwise, the `pDialog` will block your GUI.

Comment: after i put handler.execute(URL) to onStart(), the effect still the same, loading in previous activity, but dialog just appear in short time

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the work of `HttpPostHandler2` is long enough to display the `pDialog`. If it not, it will disappear really soon. 
However, you cannot display GUI in `onCreate`. To display the dialog, you should move them to `onStart`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//GUI not ready: nothing is shown
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  HttpPostHandler2 handler = new HttpPostHandler2();

}

@Override
protected void onStart () {//GUI is ready
   String URL ="http://xxxxxx";
   handler.execute(URL);
}
```

See comment for more information.

Comment: after i put  handler.execute(URL) to onStart(), the effect still the same, loading in previous activity, but dialog just appear in short time

Comment: i just call this by clicking button from last activity `guest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FrontActivity.this,
      WomCoinActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);

   }

  });`

Comment: So I'm afraid that the problem now could be the `doInBackground`. Did you get the desired result?

Comment: What do you mean by the problem now could be the doInBackground?
I got the result, but the 2s loading time make the app looks like hanged