# Android - Loading data from internet

Tags: android, dialog, httprequest, splash-screen

I am new to Android. I would like to ask , if i have 2 pages and page2 need some data from internet with some parameters from page1.

I should

**A) Load the data (HTTPREQUEST) in page1 when i click the button and pass it by** intent

or

**B) pass the parameter by intent and load the data (HTTPREQUEST) in page2**

what people normally handle this? And where should the loading dialog show??

This should be use frequently in an app, anyone have a example for this??

Comment: You may directly call webservice from page2.If you call from first page then you have to send it to second page.That double work.I hope this one will help to you :)

Comment: But i encounter this problem when using the loading dialog --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755795/display-dialog-when-loading-internet

Answer (score 2):

Use the Approach "B".

- On Button Click of Page1 pass data via intent to Page2.
- Fetch parameter from intent in Page2.
- Make HttpRequest asynchronously with fetched parameter.
- During asynchronous HttpRequest show the Loading dialog.
- On completion of fetching data update your UI with new data.

Comment: But i encounter this problem when using the loading dialog --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758700/android-loading-data-from-internet

Comment: What problem? The given link redirect me to this page only.

Comment: If I want to show loading dialog on Page 1 but use approach B as suggested, is it possible?? How can I do that?
I've already done fetching and displaying part but showing loading on page B(which is blank while loading)

Comment: sorry,this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755795/display-dialog-when-loading-internet

Comment: You have any idea of it?

Answer (score 0):

Go with..

**B) pass the parameter by intent and load the data (HTTPREQUEST) in page2**

And show the loading dialog on **page2**

Comment: If I want to show loading dialog on Page 1 but use approach B as suggested, is it possible?? How can I do that?

Comment: But i encounter this problem when using the loading dialog --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755795/display-dialog-when-loading-internet

Comment: You have any idea of it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use android-async-http for getting data from internet.

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http